# Convey different meanings of "badly", keeping the wordplay

Tags: traduction, anglais, jeux-de-mots

> When I was a teen, I wanted to play the drums so badly. Now after
> decades of practice, I'm 40 and have achieved my goal.  I can play the
> drums badly!
>
> Quand j'étais ado, je voulais tellement jouer de la batterie.
> Maintenant, après des décennies de pratique, j'ai 40 ans et j'ai
> atteint mon objectif. Je peux mal jouer de la batterie.

In the former case badly expresses to a great or serious degree; in the latter it expresses
in an unsatisfactory, inadequate, or unsuccessful way.

Are there other ways to convey this contrast in French keeping, if possible, the wordplay present in English?

Comment: "Curiouser and curiouser!"  cried Alice (in Wonderland)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Il est rare de pouvoir traduire un jeu de mot en gardant les mêmes équivalences, mais il y a suffisamment de mots qui veulent à peu près dire « beaucoup » pour pouvoir faire des jeux de mots similaires.

Par exemple, *[énormément](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9norm%C3%A9ment)* veut dire *beaucoup* (en plus intense), et un des sens du mot *[énormité](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9normit%C3%A9)* est quelque chose d'atroce (soit quelque chose qui est vraiment un crime grave, soit quelque chose de tellement déplaisant qu'on peut dire par exagération que c'est un crime).

> Quand j'étais adolescent, je voulais énormément jouer de la batterie. Maintenant, après des décennies de pratique, je peux jouer des énormités à la batterie.

Normalement, en français de France, on dirait qu'on *sait* jouer d'un instrument. Mais dans ce contexte, « je sais » ne marche pas très bien : il sous-entendrait que jouer mal est une compétence qui vient en plus de savoir jouer bien. « Je peux » est plus adapté, mais il laisse quand même un peu sentir quelque chose d'inattendu avant la fin de la phrase.

On peut aussi combiner les formes actives et passives de *[désespérer](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A9sesp%C3%A9rer)*. Par exemple :

> Quand j'étais adolescent, je voulais désespérément apprendre à jouer de la batterie. Maintenant, après des décennies de pratique, je sais jouer à la batterie de façon déspérante.

L'adjectif *[méchamment](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%C3%A9chamment)* peut lui aussi signifier « beaucoup ». Il ne convient pas vraiment pour le jeu de mot lorsqu'il s'agit de jouer d'un instrument, mais il peut permettre un jeu de mot du même type avec d'autres activités.

L'adverbe *[gravement](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/gravement)*, éventuellement sous la forme *grave* (mais employé adverbialement), peut signifier « beaucoup » en langage familier. Et, en langage familier, *[grave](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/grave)* peut être une manière de critiquer quelque chose ou quelqu'un comme étant fou, incompétent ou autres caractéristiques négatives. Le cas particulier d'un instrument de musique rajoute un rapprochement avec *grave* signifiant un son de fréquence basse (le contraire d'*aigu*), ce qui peut être désirable ou non.

> Quand j'étais ado, je voulais jouer de la batterie, grave. Maintenant, quand je joue de la batterie, c'est grave.

(Attention, j'ai mis des liens vers le Wiktionnaire dans mon message, mais il n'est pas vraiment complet sur les sens figurés ou familiers.)

Comment: "Je voulais [grave] jouer de la batterie," sounds more natural to my ears, although my French is stuck a few years back, so that may have changed since then?

Comment: @Kaiido Either works

Answer (score 2):

Using Quebec French you can pull it off but it's a bit of a stretch... you need to extend the meaning (and, arguably, syntax) of the adverb [*dur*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/dur#Adverbe) (forcefully, intensely) into "very much" but it sort of works because of the topic (playing the drums involves hitting them), then use an idiomatic expression (QC fam., [*faire dur*](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/dur#e5a01bf90d3cce8e)) alluding to *inadequacy* for contrast:

> Quand j'étais jeune, je voulais jouer de la batterie *vraiment dur*.
> Aujourd'hui, après des décennies de pratique, j'ai 40 ans et j'ai
> atteint mon objectif. Je joue de la batterie et *ça fait dur* !

Similarly, you can use "*(croire) [dur comme fer](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/dur_comme_fer)*" in the first statement, but then it's no longer about wanting but rather about believing... that you would (*je croyais dur comme fer qu'un jour j'allais jouer de la batterie, que j'allais devenir batteur*.).

Answer (score 1):

Voilà une version qui fonctionne exactement de la même manière que l'original :

> Quand j'étais ado, je voulais très salement jouer de la batterie. Maintenant, après des décennies de pratique, j'ai 40 ans et j'ai atteint mon objectif. Je peux en jouer très salement.

C'est tout de même un vrai coup de chance qu'en plus de respecter les deux sens, on puisse reproduire l'ambiguité grammaticale de la première phrase comme ça.

Comment: Quels registre et origine geographique, pour "vouloir très salement" ? Il y a bien évidemment le populaire "salement amoché" etc. mais je ne crois pas avoir jamais entendu "vouloir très salement"